# Dynamic UITableView rowheight and max row height using ios8 auto-resizing cell?

Tags: ios8, uitableview

I want to implement dynamic row height in UITableView with a max row height to limit the rows into such as no more than 10 lines(The row has only one label). If a row has less than 10 lines, its content will be displayed fully. If more than 10, it will display 10 lines and truncated. 
Can I implement this using auto-resizing feature of iOS8? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was working a whole day on using Auto Layout in UITableView for dynamic cell on iOS7, which use a dummy UITableViewCell and heightForRowAtIndexPath: and is very complicated. Failed!

There is a simple way to achieve this:

```
cell.ContentLabel.numberOfLines = 10;
```

yes, a simple line of code in configureCell. It limits the label in 10 lines, and it is dynamic row height with iOS8 auto-resizing:

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0;
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```